# how consider the space as character

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, whitespace

I am trying to create the "Typing practice" website. In their I want to show the space also, the next typing character shown using background:green. It is perfectly working on every character space too, but when the space is occur end of the line the background color will not apply to the white space.

[image]

I wrote in span and applied the following css

```
    if(char)==" ")
        temp_space="background-color: green;-moz-border-radius: 5px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px green;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px green;box-shadow: 0 1px 4px green;";
    else
        temp_space="";

'<span id="aa'+const_count+'" style="background:green;'+temp_space+'"><u>'+next_character+'</u>'
```

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to use the `-moz-` prefix on `border-radius` or `drop-shadow`, Firefox has long supported the unprefixed versions of those.

Comment: You should show a piece of code that actually demonstrates the issue. So it should contain minimal HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, to show exactly this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting a regular space there, you should add a non-breaking space, `&nbsp;`.

Comment: actually their add like '<span id="aa'+const_count+'" style="background:green;'+temp_space+'"><u> </u>'. and if the space is end before the div size it will work perfect like "jkl " by that marked image.

Comment: So instead of the literal space, put a `&nbsp;` inside the `<u>`.

Comment: Thanks for an idea, but " " and &nbsp; are different, so I Assigned the value like below "&nbsp" char code is 160

var value=text.charCodeAt(0))==160?" ":text